# Getting Chrome freezed with a setInterval function and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

lets see if someone can help me here with an issue making a countdown with react. I'm trying to set the minutes and secs clicking on + and - and then passing the secs to a new variable called tottime. And then, when the user clicks on Go!, a count down should be triggered but.. its not happening and I dont know why Chome keeps getting freezed.

You can check the whole project here https://github.com/staranco/react-scoreboard

Heres the code:

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          secs: 0,
          mins: 0,
          tottime: 0
        };
    this.clickSum  = this.clickSum.bind(this);
    this.clickDif  = this.clickDif.bind(this);
    this.initCount  = this.initCount.bind(this);
  }

  clickSum() {
    if(this.state.secs < 59) {
      this.setState({secs: this.state.secs + 1});
    } else {
      this.setState({secs: 0});
      this.setState({mins: this.state.mins + 1});
    }
    this.setState({tottime: (this.state.secs + 1) + (this.state.mins * 60)});
    console.log(this.state.tottime)
  }

  clickDif() {
    if(this.state.secs > 0) {
     this.setState({secs: this.state.secs - 1});
     this.setState({tottime: (this.state.secs - 1) + (this.state.mins * 60)})
    } else if(this.state.mins > 0 && this.state.secs <= 0) {
      this.setState({mins: this.state.mins - 1});
      this.setState({secs: 59});
    }
  }

  initCount() {
    var self = this;
    while (self.state.tottime > 0) {
      setInterval(function() {
        console.log(self.state.tottime);
        self.setState({tottime: self.state.tottime - 1})
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="timer">
        <div className="timer_clock">
          <span>{this.state.mins}</span>:<span>{this.state.secs}</span>
        </div>

        <div className="timer_countdown"><span>{this.state.tottime}</span></div>

        <TimerBtn btnSymbol="+" onClick={this.clickSum} />
        <TimerBtn btnSymbol="-" onClick={this.clickDif} />

        <TimerBtn btnSymbol="Go!" onClick={this.initCount} />
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: You should pass a lambda to setState

Comment: you mean a fat arrow? How? where?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your code is here,

```
while(self.state.tottime > 0)
```

This condition will be always be `true` and browser will keep setting up `setIntervals` and no `setInterval` will be executed .

You can verify it by pressing the `freeze chrome` button :). You can see the `console.log` i have added will get printed a lot of times.

you can change your code to something like this,

```js
class Timer extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          secs: 0,
          mins: 0,
          tottime: 0
        };
    this.clickSum  = this.clickSum.bind(this);
    this.clickDif  = this.clickDif.bind(this);
    this.initCount  = this.initCount.bind(this);
    this.initCountOld = this.initCountOld.bind(this);
  }

  clickSum() {
    if(this.state.secs < 59) {
      this.setState({secs: this.state.secs + 1});
    } else {
      this.setState({secs: 0});
      this.setState({mins: this.state.mins + 1});
    }
    this.setState({tottime: (this.state.secs + 1) + (this.state.mins * 60)});
    console.log(this.state.tottime)
  }

  clickDif() {
    if(this.state.secs > 0) {
     this.setState({secs: this.state.secs - 1});
     this.setState({tottime: (this.state.secs - 1) + (this.state.mins * 60)})
    } else if(this.state.mins > 0 && this.state.secs <= 0) {
      this.setState({mins: this.state.mins - 1});
      this.setState({secs: 59});
    }
  }

  initCount() {
    var self = this;
    const refreshIntervalId = setInterval(()=>{
      self.setState({
        tottime: self.state.tottime - 1
      })
      if(this.state.tottime <= 0){ clearInterval(refreshIntervalId)}
  
    }, 1000)
  }
  initCountOld() {
   var self = this;
    while (self.state.tottime > 0) {
      console.log("setting infinite setintervals")
      setInterval(function() {
        console.log(self.state.tottime);
        self.setState({tottime: self.state.tottime - 1})
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="timer">
        <div className="timer_clock">
          <span>{this.state.mins}</span>:<span>{this.state.secs}</span>
        </div>

        <div className="timer_countdown"><span>{this.state.tottime}</span></div>

        <button btnSymbol="+" onClick={this.clickSum}>+</button>
        <button btnSymbol="-" onClick={this.clickDif}>-</button>

        <button btnSymbol="Go!" onClick={this.initCount}>Go</button>
        <button onClick={this.initCountOld}>Freeze chrome</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Timer />,document.getElementById("app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Many thnks! fot the code and the explanation, now I understand it... I wasnt letting the app know when to stop and it was getting crazy all the time... Thnks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `initCount()` method.

- The while will be executed infinitely - leading to a Chrome Freeze as chorme will run out of memory.

Now, you should keep two things in mind for this app:

1. When should the timer start -> When the user clicks on Go and it should start an interval for 1000 ms - You have addressed this thing.
2. When should the timer stop -> When countdown eventually reaches 0 and interval should be cleared at this time - You have not addressed this thing.

So for addressing 2 above, what you should be doing is:

1. Get rid of the `while` loop
2. Add conditional statements inside your `setInterval()`, which will determine if your countdown has to stop or if it has to continue. If it has to be stop, then you should clear the interval which was associated with the countdown

Now how to clear the interval? Read on

`setInterval()` returns an `id`, which you can save in some variable and then you can use `clearInterval()` and pass that `id` to it to clear the interval.

For e.g.:

```
var id = setInterval(foo, 1000);
clearInterval(id);
```

So your `initCount()` has to be something like this (I've commented out the wrong code):

```
  initCount() {
    var self = this;
    //while (self.state.tottime > 0) {
      self.intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        console.log(self.state.tottime);
        if(self.state.tottime > 0) {
          // Decrease tottime if its not zero
          self.setState({tottime: self.state.tottime - 1});
        } else {
          // Clear the timer if tottime == 0
          clearInterval(self.intervalId);
        }
      }, 1000);
   // }
  }
```

Here is the a sample that I created with the code from your github repo [Countdown Sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRygEE)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thnks a lot you too, your explanations is really good, and I finally got it now

Comment: it is better to use the callback of `setState` because you cannot be certain that the first `setState` completes before the second. In this example the delay between iterations are `1000ms` which is way enough. But what happens if we use `10ms`? Then we cannot be sure.

Comment: I agree with you Chris. But I think here only one interval should be running at a time. A better approach would be to disable Go button while the countdown is running

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `setState()` updates the state asynchronously, meaning that you cannot accurately predict when exactly the state will update.

Have a look at the official documentation of setState, [**here**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> Think of `setState()` as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.
>
> `setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling `setState()` a potential pitfall. Instead, use `componentDidUpdate` or a `setState callback (setState(updater, callback))`, either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied.

---

#### The issue

So what happens in your code is that you select a starting value of `tottime`, but when you hit <kbd>Go!</kbd>, the following happens:

1. `self.state.tottime > 0` is true. We enter the while-loop.
2. You initiate an interval with a callback to be executed in 1 second. The while-loop doesn't wait for the callback to finish, and instead starts a new iteration of the loop and a new interval is created. Again and again and again...
3. You have now enqueued probably thousands of callbacks by the time the *first* callback 1000ms delay has ran out.
4. The loop continues and more callbacks are queued because `self.state.tottime > 0` is still true.
5. The queue is so big, your browser freezes.

---

#### Solution

To solve this, try changing your `initCount()` function into this instead:

```
initCount() {
  var self = this;
  this.interval = setInterval(function() {
    self.setState({tottime: self.state.tottime - 1}, function() {
      if(self.state.tottime == 0) {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        this.interval = null;
      }
    })
  }, 1000);
}
```

**Working demo below:**

I've simplified your component slightly for demo purposes.

```js
class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      secs: 0,
      mins: 0,
      tottime: 10
    };
    this.initCount = this.initCount.bind(this);
  }

  initCount() {
    var self = this;
    this.interval = setInterval(function() {
      self.setState({tottime: self.state.tottime - 1}, function() {
        if(self.state.tottime == 0) {
          clearInterval(this.interval);
          this.interval = null;
        }
      })
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="timer">
        <div className="timer_clock">
          <span>{this.state.mins}</span>:<span>{this.state.secs}</span>
        </div>

        <div className="timer_countdown"><span>{this.state.tottime}</span></div>

        <button onClick={this.initCount}>Go!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Timer />, document.getElementById("myApp"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="myApp"></div>
```

Comment: Wow! many thnks you too, for a begginer like me, its really meaningful that more experienced people like you expend time on my shitty code and explaining everything. Thnks a lot again!